# How to pass a partial html.erb form from js.erb file instead of just a message?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement jquery on a sample ruby on rails app. I just started to explore the js. I know I have so much to learn in js/jquery. Right now there is something I am stuck with.

I have a `js.erb` file as follows:

**js.erb**

```
<% if @phone_number.verified %>
  $('#verify-pin').hide()
  $('#status-box').removeClass()
  $('#status-box').addClass('alert alert-success')
  $('#status-message').text('Verified!!')
<% else %>
  $('#status-box').removeClass()
  $('#status-box').addClass('alert alert-warning')
  $('#status-message').text("Sorry, that wasn't the right pin.")
<% end %>
$('#status-box').fadeToggle()
```

If you see the 5th line, right now I am just flashing a text message "Verified!!" when the the condition is true. But instead I want display a **partial erb** form. I have a **_form.html.erb** file. How can I display this instead of a text message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the [`escape_javascript`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript) method.

```
$('#status-message').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'form) %>");
```

It is also aliased as just `j`

```
$('#status-message').html("<%= j(render 'form) %>");
```

Obviously you might want to do some more fancy stuff with this, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: Just to test in the partial **form** I just added `<%= @phone_number %>`. The variable `@phone_number` stores the number like "3843849394". But it is displaying memory location like `#&lt;PhoneNumber:0x007f85adfc7170&gt;` instead of the number.

Comment: You might have to change `text` to `html`.

Comment: Changed it to `  $('#status-message').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'form') %>")` now its displaying `#<PhoneNumber:0x007f85ad502168>`

Comment: Ok, then `@phone_number` is a `PhoneNumber` object, not a number.

Comment: Yes, but you must provide some property to it like `@phone_number.number` or something. How are you doing it in the controller?

Comment: Try doing `@phone_number.inspect`, then you'll see what I mean

Answer (score 1):

While you do have .js.erb and could use erb directly in your JS, I want to show a workaround that'll work for those without .js.erb (eg with .coffee formats) and that will work for all build stacks.

In your application.html.erb, add a script tag and initiate a global variable, then you can use that variable to append a partial whenever you might need the partial. Like this:

```
<script>
    partials = {
        foobarPartial: '<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'foobar', :locals => { :local_var_1 => false, :local_var_2 => 'foo' }) %>'
    };
</script>
```

Then, whenever you need that partial, just add it via .html(partials.foobarPartial)